# Get XML element by ID with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm having some difficulties getting PHP to read my XML document. I'm trying to echo the content from each  node based on whatever catid I've selected.

XML: text.xml

```
<root>
  <category catid='1'>
    <text id='TXT1'><![CDATA[ Lorem Ipsum ]]></text>
    <text id='TXT2'><![CDATA[ Lorem Ipsum ]]></text>
    <text id='TXT3'><![CDATA[ Lorem Ipsum ]]></text>
  </category>
  <category catid='2'>
    <text id='TXT1'><![CDATA[ Lorem Ipsum ]]></text>
    <text id='TXT2'><![CDATA[ Lorem Ipsum ]]></text>
    <text id='TXT3'><![CDATA[ Lorem Ipsum ]]></text>
  </category>
</root>
```

PHP:

```
<?php  
$xml = simplexml_load_file('/path/to/text.xml');
$category = $xml->xpath("//category[@catid='1']/text");
$ids = ['TXT1', 'TXT2', 'TXT3'];

foreach($ids as $id){
  echo $category[$id]; //I'm not quite sure how to do this bit.
}
?>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You can do exactly the same for `@id=` as you did for the `@catid=` in the second line of code. Any reason you didn't try that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here comes an example how to do it using the DOM extension together with XPATH:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);

$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

$result = $selector->query("//category[@catid='1']");
if($result->length !== 1) {
    die('BAD xml');
}

$category = $result->item(0);
$ids = array('TXT1', 'TXT2', 'TXT3');

foreach($ids as $id){
    // note $category as the second argument. meaning that the query
    // is relative to the category node and not to the root node
    $textResult = $selector->query("text[@id='$id']", $category);
    if($textResult->length < 1) {
        die('BAD xml');
    }

    $text = $textResult->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo $text, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Note that this should also possible using simple_xml. I had just no example at hand. Maybe I'll prepare one for completeness if I have time. see you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use DOMDocument::getElementById, for more see [getElementById](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php).